# Naïve Bayes Classifier Bernoulli model

Tags: machine-learning, probability, text-classification, naivebayes, bernoulli-probability

I'm working on classifying invoices and receipt and I will be working with Bernoulli model.

This is the naive Bayes classifier :

P(c|x) = P(x|c) x P(c) / P(x)

I know how to compute P(c) class prior probability and since we assume that all the words are independent we don't need the P(x).

Now formula will be like this : P(c|x) = P(x|c) x P(c) and to compute P(x|c) we do the liklihood method which is calculating all the words probability P(c|X) = P(x1|c)P(x2|c)*P(x3|c)....

My question  is after calculating the liklihood do I need to multiply it with P(c) or not, P(c|X) = P(x1|c)P(x2|c)*P(x3|c)...*P(c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P(c|x)` **is not** equal to  `P(x|c) P(c)`. It is **proportional**, as during classification you do

```
cl(x) = arg max_c P(c|x) = arg max_c P(x|c) P(c) / P(x) = arg max_c P(x|c) P(c)
```

and this holds for **every probability distribution**, where `P(x)>0`, no need to any Bayes assumptions at this point. It is just a simple Bayes theorem + noticing that `P(x)` is just a positive constant in this equation.

Thus you **never** actually compute `P(c|x)`, you just compute `P(x|c) P(c)` which will give you **the same classification**. I hope this shows that your classification **has to be** based on product of `P(x|c)` and `P(c)`, where as you pointed out `P(x|c) = PROD_i P(x_i|c)` (here we use Naive Bayes assumption regarding independence, not before).